# Why do I get incompatible types when I am giving ? extends in both class and return

Tags: java, dictionary, incompatibletypeerror

In one of my classes I have...

```
public Class<? extends Map<K, V>> getObjectType() {
    return (Class<? extends Map<K, V>>) Map.class;
}
```

What is wrong with this code

I keep getting

```
error: incompatible types: Class <Map> cannot be converted to Class<extends Map<K,V>>
    return (Class<? extends Map<K, V>>) Map.class;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) should answer your question

Comment: So should I use `super` instead of `extends`

Comment: What should `Class<? extends Map<K, V>>` represent in the first place? There is no class `Map<K, V>` only `Map` due to type erasure.

Answer (score 0):

K and V aren't actual types and would be erased by type erasure anyway. Just use Map. And there is no need to cast. You only cast to a more specific type and Map.class is an instance of `Class<? extends Map>`.

```
public Class<? extends Map> getObjectType() {
    return Map.class;
}
```

other examples using compatible types:

```
public Class<? extends Map> getObject1Type() {
    return HashMap.class;
}

public Class<? extends Map> getObject2Type() {
    return LinkedHashMap.class;
}
```